# field has incomplete type - unions & structs

Tags: c, struct, types, field, union

I have these types:

```
struct netlib_nw {
  int id;
  union netlib_op op;
};

union netlib_op {
  struct netlib_op_readdir op_readdir;
  struct netlib_op_readdir_recv op_readdir_recv;
};

struct netlib_op_readdir {
  char* path;
};

struct netlib_op_readdir_recv {
  char** recv;
};
```

I have them cause I wanna tranfer the `netlib_nw` via network with different stuff in it.

Here is the error I get:

```
error: field has incomplete type 'union netlib_op'
  union netlib_op op;
                  ^
note: forward declaration of 'union netlib_op'
  union netlib_op op;
```

How to solve that? I do not understand what's wrong with that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just like you do, the compiler reads source files from the top to the bottom. Just as you, it will get confused if it encounters a variable declaration of a type which has not been previously defined anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just rearrange the definitions:

```
struct netlib_op_readdir {
    char* path;
};

struct netlib_op_readdir_recv {
    char** recv;
};

union netlib_op {
    struct netlib_op_readdir op_readdir;
    struct netlib_op_readdir_recv op_readdir_recv;
};

struct netlib_nw {
    int id;
    union netlib_op op;
};
```

The issue is that in the original code, while parsing `netlib_nw` sees a declaration of type `netlib_op` but that type is not defined (thus it is incomplete). If for example you had used a member which is a pointer or reference to `netlib_nw` then everything would be fine since you can use them with a forward declared class.

So by rearranging the structures so that they are defined in order of dependencies you get rid of the error.